# accession session object in WT forms

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am trying to populate roles depending updon the id of organization, but seems that WT forms doesn't support session

## view.py

```
@users.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@users.route('/manage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def manage_users():
    form = User_Form()
    return render_template('account/manage_users.html', form=form)
```

## user_form.py

```
from flask import session
from wtforms import Form, SelectField, TextField, PasswordField, validators

class User_Form(Form, session):
    username = TextField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    password = PasswordField('New Password', [
        validators.Required(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField(u'Repeat Password')
    email = TextField(u'Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    active = SelectField(u'Active', choices=[('1', 'True'), ('0', 'False')])

    organization_id = session['user_id']
    #role = "list roles according to organization_id"
```

---

File "C:\Users\dell\Envs\surveyApp\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 20, in _lookup_req_ob
ject
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context

Comment: You can't inherit from `session` like that. What is the purpose of the `organization_id` field if you can already access it via a session variable?

Comment: The application have multiple organizations registered and inividual organization can create their own role leading to different role list for individual organization. And while creating user I want organization id to list corresponding roles for that organization.

Answer (score 1):

As blender told, you can't use session in that way. Only way I can think of is use session in views and send necessary data while rendering template.

view.py

```
@users.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@users.route('/manage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def manage_users():
    form = User_Form()
    form.organization_id.data = session['user_id']
    return render_template('account/manage_users.html', form=form)
```

And mark 'organization_id' as TextField in  forms:

```
class User_Form(Form, session):
    # Other fields
    organization_id = TextField()
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to set the choices based on logic in the view.:

```
def manage_users():
    form = User_Form()
    if session['user_id'] == 1:
        form.role.choices = [('Role1', 'Label1'), ('Role2', 'Label2')]
    else:
        form.role.choices = [...]
    if form.validate():
        ...

    return render_template('account/manage_users.html', form=form)
```

As long as the choices are set before `validate()` is called, then you can change them how you see fit.

For reference see [SelectField from Dynamic Choices](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.5/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField)  in the WTForms docs.